# Web harvest failing to convert malformed html to xml

Tags: java, webharvest

I am using xquery processor in web harvest (from java) to parse an html page that contains an invalid tag inside a `<div>` element, like `<div 3px="abc">`. The exception is:

```
SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Element type "div" must be followed by either
attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.XQueryProcessor.execute(Unknown Source)
```

Is there a quick way to clean the div pre-processing? Or any workaround for this problem?

Comment: try lookin at JTidy http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/